# How can I override .env variables with command line arguments in Vue 3 project?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

I have .env file that contains environment variable such as:

```
VUE_APP_BRAND=Brand1
```

I use these at build time to dynamically load components based on this parameter.

Now when I run `npm run build` I'd like to specify brand by passing in the command line argument which will override this one in `.env` file. Is this possible? I tried following but none works:

- `npm run build VUE_APP_BRAND=Brand2`
- `npm run build -- VUE_APP_BRAND=Brand2`
- `npm run build -- --VUE_APP_BRAND=Brand2`

This is my test project so I am using `@vue/cli-service v5.0.0-beta.2` which is based on `Webpack 5`.

Comment: I suggest you to use separate env files containing different values of BRAND

Comment: Shouldn't it work if you put `VUE_APP_BRAND=Brand2` before the `npm` call? See posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If using macOS/Linux, you can specify environment variables in the same command by prefixing the setting to the command:

```sh
VUE_APP_BRAND=Brand2 npm run build
```

If you need something cross-platform, use [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env):

```sh
npx cross-env VUE_APP_BRAND=Brand2 npm run build
```